# Upgrade M2.4.1 Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\LoginAsCustomerApi\Api\GetLoggedAsCustomerAdminIdInterface

Tags: magento2, upgrade

When running upgrade we see no errors but on running the frontend we are surprised with this nice errror statement

`Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\LoginAsCustomerApi\Api\GetLoggedAsCustomerAdminIdInterface`

Is this a know problem or is there a smart way to solve it?

```
Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\LoginAsCustomerApi\Api\GetLoggedAsCustomerAdminIdInterface in /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50 Stack trace: 
#0 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() 
#1 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(167): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() 
#2 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(273): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument() 
#3 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(236): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument() 
#4 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime() 
#5 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments() 
#6 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() 
#7 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php(250): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get() 
#8 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(144): Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList->getPlugin() 
#9 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\PageCache\Model\Config\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() 
#10 /generated/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/Config/Interceptor.php(65): Magento\PageCache\Model\Config\Interceptor->___callPlugins() 
#11 /vendor/mirasvit/module-cache-warmer/src/CacheWarmer/Plugin/Debug/OnHitPlugin.php(139): Magento\PageCache\Model\Config\Interceptor->isEnabled() 
#12 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Mirasvit\CacheWarmer\Plugin\Debug\OnHitPlugin->aroundAroundDispatch() 
#13 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() 
#14 /generated/code/Magento/PageCache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->___callPlugins() 
#15 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin\Interceptor->aroundDispatch() 
#16 /vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() 
#17 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() 
#18 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(116): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() 
#19 /generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() 
#20 /vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() 
#21 /pub/index.php(40): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() 
#22 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly why you are having this problem, but if you are not using the Login as customer module you can always disable it:

```
bin/magento module:disable Magento_LoginAsCustomer Magento_LoginAsCustomerApi Magento_LoginAsCustomerAdminUi Magento_LoginAsCustomerAssistance Magento_LoginAsCustomerFrontendUi Magento_LoginAsCustomerLog Magento_LoginAsCustomerPageCache Magento_LoginAsCustomerQuote Magento_LoginAsCustomerSales
```

Edit:
I was recently having this problem when I upgraded to Magento 2.4.1. The problem is that you might have some modules that are disabled in your old installation, then when you upgrade Magento installs new modules that are dependent on the ones you already have disabled. Most likely you have many disabled modules, try to run:

```
bin/magento module:status
```

Either you can try to figure out which module to enable or you can start with testing to enable all modules and see if that solves the problem.

```
bin/magento module:enable --all
```

Comment: Maybe 1 of the sub modules was already disabled that is needed by some other? There are just too many modules nowadays ... I will try this thx

Comment: The problem is that bin/magento is also broken of ... `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\MediaGallerySynchronizationApi\Model\ImportFilesInterface in /home/sohbv/public_html/m2_dev/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50` not happy with them upgrades ;(

Comment: I'm having the same issue did you find a solution ? Thanks !

Comment: Not sure what it can be, start with deleting the generated folder. The error is cast because the object can not in this case initiate Magento\MediaGallerySynchronizationApi\Model\ImportFilesComposite Do u have this file? Could it be related to access rights ? Do you have the correct version of php ?

Comment: Yes I checked everything (php version, remove generated/code folder etc... but still getting the issue

Comment: I updated the answer, please have a look